# How to use groupBy with orderBy on Array to XMl in Mule4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I having input as Array (json) which needs to `groupBy` and `orderBy` with `clientId` so that its internal `Lines` are grouped and ordered in to one root in xml (repetitive lines of clientId). I'm stuck how to use dataweave  for the XMl response. Please find the request and expected response.

Request:

```
 [
    {
     "ClientId": 2,
     "Code": "string",
     "ReceivedDate": "2018-10-23",
     "ReceivedTime": "2217",
     "Warehouse": "30",
     "Quantity": "20"
   },
   {
     "ClientId": 1,
     "Code": "string",
     "ReceivedDate": "2018-10-23",
     "ReceivedTime": "2217",
     "Warehouse": "56",
     "Quantity": "20"
  },
  {
     "ClientId": 1,
     "Code": "string",
     "ReceivedDate": "2018-10-23",
     "ReceivedTime": "2217",
     "Warehouse": "70",
     "Quantity": "20"
  }
  
]
```

Response

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <Receipt>
   <client clientId="1">
     <code>string</code>
     <Lines>
       <Warehouse>56</Warehouse>
       <Quantity>20</Quantity>
     </Lines>
     <Lines>
       <Warehouse>70</Warehouse>
       <Quantity>20</Quantity>
     </Lines>
   </client>
   <client  clientId="2">
     <code>string</code>
     <Lines>
       <Warehouse>30</Warehouse>
       <Quantity>20</Quantity>
     </Lines>
   </client>
 </Receipt>
```

Let me if question is unclear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, comments are embedded in the code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml

var data =  [
    {
     "ClientId": 2,
     "Code": "string",
     "ReceivedDate": "2018-10-23",
     "ReceivedTime": "2217",
     "Warehouse": "30",
     "Quantity": "20"
   },
   {
     "ClientId": 1,
     "Code": "string",
     "ReceivedDate": "2018-10-23",
     "ReceivedTime": "2217",
     "Warehouse": "56",
     "Quantity": "20"
  },
  {
     "ClientId": 1,
     "Code": "string",
     "ReceivedDate": "2018-10-23",
     "ReceivedTime": "2217",
     "Warehouse": "70",
     "Quantity": "20"
  }
]

---
Receipt: do {
    // Group by the data
    var groupedData = data groupBy $.ClientId
    // Order the client Ids
    var orderedClientIds = groupedData pluck $$ orderBy $ as Number
    ---
    // Iterate over the ordered clientIds and create an object, hence the use of reduce
    orderedClientIds reduce (cId, cIds={}) -> cIds ++ {
        // Add the clientId attribute to the client tag
        client @(clientId: cId ): {
            // Get the code from the first element in the array
            code: groupedData[cId][0].Code,
            // Create the Lines, should you avoid repeating tags at the
            // same level with other tags?  i.e. code and Lines
            // IMHO a best practice XML should have code, a single Lines
            // and nested in Lines, one or more Line tags organizing the
            // data
            Lines: groupedData[cId]  reduce (
                (l,ls={}) -> ls ++ Lines :{
                    Warehouse: l.Warehouse,
                    Quantity: l.Quantity
                }   
            )
        }
    }
}
```

What is still unclear to me is whether you want to order the `Warehouse` and/or `Quantity` values.  I did not in the above code but you can easily do it, just let me know and I 'll amend.

EDIT: If you copy and paste the code in a `Transform Message` processor, Studio will show an error--this error is a false positive, turn on the preview or even better stick an `HTTP Listener` to the source and give it a go :)

Comment: see my answer. Sorry for format - replies do not accept images

Comment: @George Thanks for your answer. Im using Runtime 4.2.2 and anypointSudio 7.4.2 as @Alex mentioned below, on pasting your code in dwl throwing error on `reduce`. Could you please update in the above mentioned version. Thanks in advance

Comment: @George i dont want to order the `warehouse` and `quantity`. If i got the above result should be fine. i will try updating the code accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Its a false positive, turn on the preview, add an HTTP Listener and send a request.

Comment: @star I used the same code under 7.4.2/4.2.2 and it runs fine.

Comment: @George Thanks Yes it is absolutely working fine on sending Request and you are right . Great :)

Comment: @George I have used your code but  twisted logic in this link  yet to get answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021682/how-to-loop-and-combine-as-one-in-mule-dataweave/62023269?noredirect=1#comment109718148_62023269 If you have time. Could you please have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hate xml. But here's my go at it. Hope it helps.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data =  [
    {
     "ClientId": 2,
     "Code": "string",
     "ReceivedDate": "2018-10-23",
     "ReceivedTime": "2217",
     "Warehouse": "30",
     "Quantity": "20"
   },
   {
     "ClientId": 1,
     "Code": "string",
     "ReceivedDate": "2018-10-23",
     "ReceivedTime": "2217",
     "Warehouse": "56",
     "Quantity": "20"
  },
  {
     "ClientId": 1,
     "Code": "string",
     "ReceivedDate": "2018-10-23",
     "ReceivedTime": "2217",
     "Warehouse": "70",
     "Quantity": "20"
  }
]

var clients = (data orderBy $.ClientId groupBy $.ClientId)
---
{
    Receipt: clients mapObject (v,k,i) -> {client @(clientId: k): {
        code: v.Code[0]
    } ++ ((v map (item,ind) -> {
        Lines: {
            Warehouse: item.Warehouse,
            Quantity: item.Quantity
        }
    }) reduce (value, acc={}) -> acc ++ value)
    }
}
```

Gives output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Receipt>
  <client clientId="1">
    <code>string</code>
    <Lines>
      <Warehouse>56</Warehouse>
      <Quantity>20</Quantity>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
      <Warehouse>70</Warehouse>
      <Quantity>20</Quantity>
    </Lines>
  </client>
  <client clientId="2">
    <code>string</code>
    <Lines>
      <Warehouse>30</Warehouse>
      <Quantity>20</Quantity>
    </Lines>
  </client>
</Receipt>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine too. George Answered first. Thanks for try attempting the code though the question has answered. Awesome. Gotta different perspective of code on the same question. Sweet !!! Much Appreciated.

Comment: Find the one that performs the best and use it, then tick the answer :)

Comment: No worries! Not worried about winning. I use SO [dataweave] to sharpen my own skills with problems and just share my solutions. The only right answer is what works best for you.

Comment: @maddestroyer7 Updated you , In the above code if we add more `ClientId` number orderBy not working Properly.

Comment: @star I'm not sure what you're saying the issue is

Comment: @maddestroyer sorry  for confusing. I have sorted out not looking for solution. Above code works perfectly fine. But if we add more objects with different `clientId` orderBy not happening Properly. You are helping, updating you :)