# How to loop and combine as one in Mule Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have request of json and expected response one as mentioned below. It need to groupBy `clientItemCode` and i'm  halfway somewhere stuck to loop around in same. Used both `MapObject` and `reduce` combination of function. Any help will be appreciated.

```
[
{
  "ClientCode": "1",
  "ClientItemCode": "245",
  "LocationId": "CLOSED"
 },
 {
  "ClientCode": "1",
  "ClientItemCode": "245",
  "LocationId": "OPEN"
 },
    {
  "ClientCode": "2",
  "ClientItemCode": "245",
  "LocationId": "CHECKOUT"
 },
 {
  "ClientCode": "2",
  "ClientItemCode": "245",
  "LocationId": "TEST"
 },
 {
  "ClientCode": "1",
  "ClientItemCode": "123",
  "LocationId": "OPEN"
 },
 {
  "ClientCode": "1",
  "ClientItemCode": "123",
  "LocationId": "CLOSED"
 }
 ]
```

Expected Response:

```
  <Results>
  <Result>
    <ClientItemCode>123<ClientItemCode>
    <ResultLines>
      <ResultLine>
        <ClientCode>1</ClientCode>
        <From>
          <LocationId>OPEN</LocationId>
        </From>
        <To>
          <LocationId>CLOSED</LocationId>
        </To>
      </ResultLine>
       <ResultLine>
        <ClientCode>2</ClientCode>
        <From>
          <LocationId>CHECKOUT</LocationId>
        </From>
        <To>
          <LocationId>TEST</LocationId>
        </To>
      </ResultLine>
    </ResultLines>
  </Result>
  <Result>
   <CientItemCode>245<ClientItemCode>
   <ResultLines>
      <ResultLine>
        <ClientCode>1</ClientCode>
        <From>
          <LocationId>CLOSED</LocationId>
        </From>
        <To>
          <LocationId>OPEN</LocationId>
        </To>
     </ResultLine>
    </ResultLines>
  </Result>
</Results>
```

Comment: I think your output data are wrong:  You mixed up the `245` with the `123` `ClientItemCode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with, probably it could be simplified a little had I had more time to devote.  Give it a try:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var data = [
 {
  "ClientCode": "1",
  "ClientItemCode": "245",
  "LocationId": "CLOSED"
 },
 {
  "ClientCode": "1",
  "ClientItemCode": "245",
  "LocationId": "OPEN"
 },
    {
  "ClientCode": "2",
  "ClientItemCode": "245",
  "LocationId": "CHECKOUT"
 },
 {
  "ClientCode": "2",
  "ClientItemCode": "245",
  "LocationId": "TEST"
 },
 {
  "ClientCode": "1",
  "ClientItemCode": "123",
  "LocationId": "OPEN"
 },
 {
  "ClientCode": "1",
  "ClientItemCode": "123",
  "LocationId": "CLOSED"
 }
]
---
// I assume that your data are ordered and all the records that will be From and To
// are paired with one another. It is doable without making such assumption but the
// algorithm will get complex.
results: do {
    // Group by the data
    var groupedData = data map {($),(From: true) if (isEven($$))} groupBy $.ClientItemCode
    // Order the client Ids
    var orderedClientIds = groupedData pluck $$ orderBy $ as Number
    ---
    orderedClientIds reduce (cId, results={}) -> do {
        var clientItemCode = cId
        var groupedByClientICode = groupedData[cId] groupBy $.ClientCode pluck $
        ---
        results ++ {result: {
            ClientItemCode: clientItemCode,
            ResultLines: groupedByClientICode reduce (cliCode, lines={}) -> do {
                var clientCode = cliCode[0].ClientCode
                ---
                lines ++ {
                    ClientCode: clientCode,
                    ResultLine: cliCode reduce (e, acc={}) -> do {
                        var locRec = {LocationId: e.LocationId}
                        ---
                        acc ++ (if (e.From?) {From: locRec } else {To: locRec})
                    }
                }
            }
        }}
    }
}
```

I also made an assumption as I replicate in the comments: I assume that your data are ordered and all the records that will be `From` and `To` are paired with one another.

EDIT: Edited the code yet again in order to force the sorting of the `ClientItemCode` and then access each one of the values in order before all the transformations in creating `result` tags.  The rest of the code is almost the same as before.  Not sure why a simple `orderBy` did not work for you, it did for me.

Comment: Brilliant !! Thanks for the quick help on much needed time. It worked as expected.

Comment: In the above code `orderBy`  `ClientItemCode` is missing as you could see in the response above it is ordered. Sorry i missed to mentioned in wording.I have tried adding `orderBy  $.ClientItemCode groupBy $.ClientItemCode` looks like not working. Do you have any thoughts on it???

Comment: Oh you still want them ordered :). It can be done in a similar fashion to  this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61836535/how-to-use-groupby-with-orderby-on-array-to-xml-in-mule4.  I 'l get to it sometime later today.

Comment: Thanks for getting back.True i tried as mentioned in the above link as it is mostly similar, though it wasnt throwing error in dataweave, functionality of orderBy not working. Not sure where i'm missing. Waiting for your response.

Comment: I just edited the code to include the `orderBy` based the `ClientItemCode`, try it

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, by `OrderBy` not working. I tried this before too. Its strange and not sure why `orderBy` not working here.

Comment: provide with sample data that it does not work @star, the data from above are being sorted.

Comment: above data not getting sorted George :(. I getting  `<ClientItemCode>245</ClientItemCode>` comes first. Could you please double confirm `<ClientItemCode>123<ClientItemCode>` coming first?. What version of Mule you are running?  i'm using 4.2.2.

Comment: I have added the screenshot how it looks like in my question  for your reference under "Sorting issue".

Comment: Thats' perfect, Brillant :). Thank you so much for your persistent help :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the OPEN and/or CLOSED could be missing:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
Results: payload groupBy $.ClientItemCode
    mapObject ((value, key, index) -> result: {
            ClientItemCode: key,
            ResultLines: {
                From: if (value.LocationId contains "OPEN") LocationId: "OPEN" else null,
                To: if (value.LocationId contains "CLOSED") LocationId: "CLOSED" else null

            }
        } 
    )
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Results>
  <result>
    <ClientItemCode>245</ClientItemCode>
    <ResultLines>
      <From>
        <LocationId>OPEN</LocationId>
      </From>
      <To>
        <LocationId>CLOSED</LocationId>
      </To>
    </ResultLines>
  </result>
  <result>
    <ClientItemCode>123</ClientItemCode>
    <ResultLines>
      <From>
        <LocationId>OPEN</LocationId>
      </From>
      <To>
        <LocationId>CLOSED</LocationId>
      </To>
    </ResultLines>
  </result>
</Results>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But i need it dynamically because instead `close` or 'open', they is some other value could come, instead `contains` looks for all in array and put it there if one matches . I update my question accordingly to get clear picture. Please take a lot. Thanks alot

Comment: Are there always 2 records per ClientItemCode? Are they expected to be ordered?

Comment: more than 2 records and yeah expected to be ordered. Thanks for double checking. Sweet of you.

Comment: I updated my request hope that get clear to you, i dont want to get complicated so in my original post shortened it. But yes i'm looking for response one as above.  there is orderBy happening by `ClientItemCode` and `clientCode`. It was pretty similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61836535/how-to-use-groupby-with-orderby-on-array-to-xml-in-mule4/61841399#61841399 but the logic inside is different which i struggling to get it.

Comment: I wasn't clear on my question. I meant to ask if there always a from and a to location, those being the 2 records per clientitemcode. It looks so from the examples, but I want to be sure.

Comment: Yes, there is always  a from and a to location. But as i updated my request recently above there will  be chance there more than 2 records per `clientItemcode`, but always only 2 record per `clientcode`. Hope that clears. please let me know still unclear

Comment: Your sample data are nice and ordered--that is, you always have the `From` record first, followed by the `To` record immediately thereafter.  Can you confirm this is always the case?  If it is, I bet a quick map to just tag which record is what would be the start to your solution: `data map {($),(From: true) if (isEven($$)),(To: true) if (isOdd($$))}`

Comment: Thanks  @George Awesome. Yes you are right , always `From` record comes first followed by `To` Record. I will give it a go and update you.